# Accessing another model's attributes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller, belongs-to, has-one

I'm new to Rails. I'm trying to make an app where students can login in
and signup for the exam. I have a problem filtering data, where a
student can only see exams which belong to her/his year and department.

Subject has the following columns:
    `t.string  "name"`
    `t.integer "ects"`
    `t.integer "year"`
    `t.integer "professor_id"` (foreign key which relates it to
professor).

Its relationship with exam:
`has_one :exam`

Exam has the following columns:
    `t.date    "start_date"`
    `t.string  "department"`
    `t.integer "professor_id"`
    `t.integer "subject_id"`

Its relationship with exam:
`belongs_to :subject`

User has attributes year (year of study) and department. The problem is
that exam only has depatment, but it doesn't have year.

I have made this in exam.rb

```
scope :department, -> (department) { where('department == ?',
department) }
scope :year, -> (year) { where('subject.year == ?', year) }
```

Then I called these methods in exams controller (index action) and
passed the data:

```
@exams = Exam.department(current_user.department) && Exam.year(current_user.year)
```

There is a problem with a scope year, it doesn't recognize subject. When
I try to access the list of exams it says this:
    SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: subject.year: SELECT "exams".*
    FROM "exams" WHERE (subject.year == 2)

But when I include subject_id:  scope :year, -> (year) {
where('Subject.find(:subject_id).year == ?', year) }
It says there is a syntax error: 
    SQLite3::SQLException: near "(": syntax error: SELECT "exams".* FROM "exams"     WHERE (Subject.find(:subject_id).year == 2).

I have tried accessing subject attributes by using delegate and
to_params, but it didn't help. I've been googling this issue for more
than 10 days, but I haven't been able to find a solution.

I appreciate any kind of help. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updated answer, sorry my bad, didn't read the question good enough.
What you need is a join

```
Exam.joins(:subject).where(department:current_user.department).where("subjects.year = ?",2016)
```

Comment: I have tried something like this, but the problem is "year" because it is the attribute of another model: subject. I tried this code and got the error: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: exams.year: SELECT "exams".* FROM "exams" WHERE "exams"."department" = ? AND "exams"."year" = 2     I will try putting: @subjects = Subject.all in index action of exams controller.

Comment: I just passed current_user.year instead of 2016 and it worked. I had no idea that join was the problem all along. Thanks a lot.